# Show that if $x^2>y^2$ then $x>y$ for all positive real numbers

Tags: analysis

Would the solution be something like:
\begin{align*}
x^2 &>y^2 \\ xx&>yy\\
\sqrt{xx}&>\sqrt{yy}\\
x&>y
\end{align*}

I feel like I'm not proving something though.

Comment: What is your definition of $>$?

Comment: ah, I think this is the right idea I'll try to work that out

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ not $x$.

Comment: You aren't.  You can't claim $a > b \implies \sqrt a > \sqrt b $ unless you have some reason to believe that and you have utterly none.  That is precisely what you are trying to prove!  In essence, all you have done is assumed it is true and claim you have proved it simply because you assumed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$x^2>y^2$, then, $x^2-y^2>0$ but this is equal to $(x-y)(x+y)>0$. We know that $x,y> 0$, then, $x+y>0$ and because $(x-y)(x+y)>0$, thus $x-y>0$. This is equivalent to $x>y$.

Answer (score 2):

By contradiction/contrapositive. If $x\leq y$, then, since $0<x$ by assumption, we have $x^2\leq y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks correct, but you must be aware that you **could** have thought incorrectly anyway.

The step from $xx>yy$ to $\sqrt{xx}>\sqrt{yy}$ for example uses the property that $\sqrt\cdot$ is strictly increasing. Also the last step you could have thought incorrectly since $\sqrt{xx}=x$ only for positive $x$ (which is where you use that $x$ is positive), in general you have $\sqrt{xx} = |x|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t)=t^2$ for $t\ge0$.

Then $f(t)$ is increasing  function. Then if $y<x$ then $f(y)<f(x)$. Then $y^2<x^2$

[image]